# React Navigation: Organizing the App

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

A general code organization question as i am new to react native and react navigation.

**How do i organize the code?**

Currently all my working code (excluding the modules and dependencies) is in one file (app.js). I can't imagine this is the right way to do it. 
**How would i split this code out?**

**Should the pages be different in their own files in the component folder?**

If so, would i `export` them and then `import` them into this file?

Not sure how to proceed. The app.js file code is below and my entire codebase is at: https://github.com/samrao2/practiciatest

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import {
  Button,
  FormLabel,
  FormInput,
  FormValidationMessage,
  Divider } from 'react-native-elements';

//import { Button } from './src/components/Button';
//import { CardSection } from './src/components/CardSection';


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'PRACTICIA'
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }}>
<Image flex="1" resizeMode="cover" imageSrc={{ require: ('./practicialogo.PNG') }} />
<Divider style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />

<Text style={styles.textStyle}>Sign up as a...</Text>
<Divider style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
        <Button
        raised
        backgroundColor="#3399ff"
        borderRadius='20'
          onPress={() => navigate('Teacher')}
          title="TEACHER"
        />
        <Divider style={{ height: 15, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />

        <Button
        raised
        backgroundColor="green"
        borderRadius='20'
          onPress={() => navigate('Parent')}
          title="PARENT"
        />
        <Divider style={{ height: 15, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />

        <Button
        raised
        backgroundColor="brown"
        borderRadius='20'
          onPress={() => navigate('Student')}
          title="ADULT STUDENT (18+)"
        />
        <Text style={styles.text2Style}>Already Registered?</Text>
        <Button
        raised
        flex='2'
        backgroundColor="grey"
        borderRadius='20'
          onPress={() => navigate('Login')}
          title="Login"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class TeacherSignUp extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'TEACHER SIGN UP',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Sign Up</Text>
        <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
        <FormInput />
        <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
        <FormInput />
        <FormLabel>First Name</FormLabel>
        <FormInput />
        <FormLabel>LastNme</FormLabel>
        <FormInput />
        <Divider style={{ height: 10, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
        <Button
        raised
        backgroundColor="brown"
        borderRadius='0'
          // onPress={() => navigate()}
          title="SUBMIT"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
class ParentSignUp extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'PARENT SIGN UP',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Sign Up</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
class StudentSignUp extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'ADULT STUDENT SIGN UP',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Sign Up</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Login extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'LOGIN',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }}>
      <FormLabel>Email/Username</FormLabel>
      <FormInput />
      <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
      <FormInput />
      <Divider style={{ height: 10, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
      <Button
      raised
      backgroundColor="grey"
      borderRadius='0'
        // onPress={() => navigate()}
        title="SUBMIT"
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Teacher: { screen: TeacherSignUp },
  Parent: { screen: ParentSignUp },
  Student: { screen: StudentSignUp },
  Login: { screen: Login },

});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <SimpleApp />;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  textStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#617189',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10
},
text2Style: {
  alignSelf: 'center',
  color: '#617189',
  fontSize: 14,
  fontWeight: '300',
  paddingTop: 10,
  paddingBottom: 10
},
titleText: {
  fontSize: 20,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
},
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with React, but I've worked on a big Javscript UI project. In such projects, it's nice to have similar functionality in the same folder, with different types of things in different files having standardized names (my.controller.js, my.template.html, my.other.controller.js). As long as similar things are together and different things are apart, it really doesn't matter. Everything is ad-hoc.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. How should i organize the code?

There isn't a right way to organize your application. 
The aim though is to try and create modular components that come together to build the complete app. 
An additional benefit of making your app modular is that you get reusable components that you can plug in where you require them.

#### 2.Should the pages be in their own files?

Yes. May not seem obvious from a one screen app but as you start building more complex applications you'd prefer having pages in their own files.

#### 3. Will i have to export and import them ?

Yes,you will export them from their particular page and then import it into the app where you wish to use it.

Data will be passed from the main app page to the components using **props**.

---

**Folder layout with basic example**

```
App.js
Components
    - HomeScreen
    - Login Screen
    - SettingsScreen
- Config
    - Config files for any library you may have installed(example firebase)
- Helpers
    - HelperFunctions.js(reusable javascript function)
```

#### App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component, StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

import HomeScreen from './Components/HomeScreen'

export default class App extends Component{

  render(){
   return(
    <HomeScreen/>
  )
 }
}
```

#### HomeScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { 
    View,
     Text,
     StyleSheet
     } from "react-native";


export default class HomeScreen extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
            <Text> This is the home Screen></Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```